# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction

Tags: rust, anchor, solana, solana-web3js

I'm working on solana anchor program with solana web3.
When I call the function in my custom program, I'm getting

`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction`

What does this error mean and where can I get the the error details list?

I was trying to call the function from my custom program

Comment: I recommend you take the [tour] and read [ask], because to help debugging we need a [mre] and that topic is talked about in there. When you've constructed the MRE you can [edit] your post to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer.
0xc means the metadata uri is not valid when mint the NFT.